# Nutch change seed.txt doesn't work

Tags: nutch

I am using nutch 1.7 and try to crawl domain1.com using

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5
```

But after I change the urls/seed.txt delete the http://domain1.com/ and add http://domain2.com/ re-run the command above, the crawl still crawl the domain1.com not domain2.com.

Does any one know why's that?

Comment: I found the solution. I need to change the regex-urlfilter.txt file also.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I need to change the regex-urlfilter.txt file also.